# Filling a PDF Form list with PDFtk

Tags: xml, pdf, pdftk, pdf-form

I'm trying to fill a form that contains a list with options, I'm using a XML file to fill my PDF with PDFtk.

Following an example from: https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/pdftk

I made a XML file like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xfdf xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/" xml:space="preserve">
<fields>
    <field name="Name">
        <value>This name</value>
    </field>
    <field name="Surname">
        <value>This surname</value>
    </field>
    <field name="Gender">
        <value>male</value>
    </field>
    <field name="Freelance">
        <value>yes</value>
    </field>
    <field name="organisation">
        <value>1</value>
        <value>2</value>
        <value>3</value>
    </field>
</fields>
```

I'm able to fill in text fields, select a button from radio buttons and check checkboxes. The only thing that does not work is filling the list, it just shows the last value and it is not even inside the list.

Is it possible to fill it with XML/FDF/XFDF or even is it possible to do with PDFtk?